# HC05 Bluetooth - Why do some use a voltage divider and some not?

Tags: voltage, bluetooth

I have an HC05 Bluetooth module on a breakoutboard with pins for STATE/RX/TX/GND/+5V/EN.

Some tutorials say I need to use a voltage divider with two resistors, [like this tutorial.](http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-with-hc-05-bluetooth-module-in-slave-mode/)

[Others say I don't.](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/bluetooth-hc05-how-to-pair-two-modules/)

(I only posted 2 tutorials but there are many others.)

I am using it without a voltage divider, and it appears to be working fine. Do I need to use a voltage divider? Why do some say to use it, and others not?

The HC05 baud rate is 9600.  It is being used to transmit very little data.

Comment: You better read the specs about the TX/RX pins on both your arduino and the HC05 and see if they can work in the range 3.3-5v. If they can't - the guys who use without voltage divider are wrong, and potentially going to break their HW..

Comment: Yes, the breakout board the hc05 uses can be powered w/5V. And I'm not using an arduino, I'm using a tty cable and communicating through my PC (although eventually I will use arduino). Are you saying even if I powered the hc05 breakout board w/5V I still need a voltage divider?

Comment: It's not about power, but about the signal levels on the interface pins

Answer (score 2):

It looks they do that as a simple form of level shifting between 5V and 3.3V. If you have a device with 5V tolerant inputs, you don't need to do anything special. Check your data sheet for details on what is supported -- it's usually a nice selling point for 3.3V devices and is often called out on the first page / marketing material.

Check out the tips here in Chapter 8: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/01146B.pdf for more ways of doing level conversion.

Comment: Yes the hc05 supports and I power it w/5v, but in those tutorials I posted it's being powered w/5v too and they still use a voltage divider. Does not using a voltage divider make it consume more battery or something?

Comment: It's not the HC-05 that matters, it's what what you connect it too. If you mate it to a 3.3V-tolerant micro, you need to level shift.

Comment: I don't know if you've worked with the hc05 breakoutboard as shown in those tutorials, but the chip is on a breakoutboard. The breakoutboard has some kind of voltage converter, allowing 5v's for a normally 3.3v only chip. The breakout board is being powered w/5v.... is that clear?

Comment: Got it -- the tutorials are worried in the other direction, about the Arduino 5V I/O affecting the 3.3V I/O on the HC-05. In this case, the only time you need to be concerned is if the device outputting into the HC-05 is not 3.3V.

Comment: OK, so lets say my arduino is powered w/3.3V and the hc05 breakoutboard powered w/5v (or vice versa) - if I understand right - then I have to use a voltage divider on the UART? However, if both my arduino board & hc05 breakoutboard are powered w/5v, then I can connect the rx/tx lines directly to each other w/no additional resistors/voltage dividers, and no negative side effects? This isn't going to make it consume more battery or anything like that?

Comment: No -- IF you are using the HC-05 breakout board you have described that has an on-board 3.3V regulator and has 3.3V I/O, then you have to do nothing special when interfacing with a 3.3V Arduino. A voltage divider will use a little more power, yes, but nothing to write home about.

Comment: But my arduino (and most I know of) are 5v. The hc05 breakout board is being powered w/5v. Do I need to use additional resistors or not? Sorry man, I'm really new with electronics. Can you just tell me which of the tutorials is correct?

Comment: I would say the first one with the voltage divider is more correct, because at least they are thinking about that issue. From some brief Googling, it looks as if the breakout boards vary wildly in terms of what they actually do. We can discuss more in chat if you want, I think after this, SE should spawn a chat window.

Comment: Yup, they're poorly documented. I have a lot of questions, maybe an hour or two's worth and would be willing to pay you if you can help. How do I start the chat with you?

Comment: You can email me (see profile) and I'll update the answer here with what we discuss if you'd like -- otherwise, hopefully at this point SE will auto-spawn a chat

Comment: Thanks, writing an email right now, will be there in 10 or 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking into same issue, this explanation clarified it for me: https://www.arxterra.com/hc-05-bluetooth-module-analysis/

In short, Arduinos run 5 V, hc05 runs 3.3 V logic, that requires resistor bridge to drop the Arduinos TX line down to 3.3 V, but due to the Arduino input accepting 3.3 V as a pass, there is no need to boost the hc05 TX line up to 5 V into the Arduino.